# Change source of listbox when different option in option group checked

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Relationship between tables : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvogz.png I have 4 tables, left table is "Owner" and info about the owner, the middle-left table is "Order" and it contains info about order, middle-right table connects "Order" table and "About air conditioner" table.
So I made form that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDUb.png
I want when "Nije započeto" in option group is marked to show only owners who have "Status predmeta"[in Narudžba table]="Nije započeto". So when "U procesu" option group would be marked I want to show only owners that have "U procesu" in "Status predmeta" field.

I wrote some code but it is not working.

```
Private Sub Okvir17_AfterUpdate()

If Frame2 = 1 Then 'Nije započeto
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik " _
            & "WHERE [Status predmeta] = 'Nije započeto' " _

If Frame2 = 2 Then 'U procesu
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik " _
            & "WHERE [Status predmeta] = 'U procesu' " _

If Frame2 = 3 Then 'Na čekanju
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik " _
            & "WHERE [Status predmeta] = 'Na čekanju' " _

If Frame2 = 4 Then 'Fakturirati
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik " _
            & "WHERE [Status predmeta] = 'Fakturirati' " _


If Frame2 = 5 Then 'Završeno
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik " _
            & "WHERE [Status predmeta] = 'Završeno' " _


End If

List2.RowSource = strRowsource1

End Sub
```

Comment: Define *not working*, please. [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Pending clarification of *not working* as requested by @Andre, in the meantime I would suggest that if you're checking the value of Frame2 then this code should possibly be in the Frame2_AfterUpdate event code rather than Okvir17_AfterUpdate.

Comment: Yes, it should be Frame2, I changed that and now I am getting this when I open form and select any option.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JGHd5YZ.png. As I mentioned in some comment below I think problem is that "Status predmeta" is not from "Vlasnik" table, because when I change condition to anything regarding "Vlasnik" table it's working.

Comment: When I changed condition to -> & "WHERE Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke] = 'AMD' " it was filtering listbox correctly so problem is checking field from another table which is connected to "Vlasnik" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I had to make INNER JOIN. Final code :

```
Private Sub Frame2_Click()

If Frame2 = 1 Then 'Nije započeto
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, Narudžba.[Status predmeta] " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik INNER JOIN Narudžba ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudžba.ID_VU " _
            & "WHERE Narudžba.[Status predmeta] = 'Nije započeto' " _



ElseIf Frame2 = 2 Then 'U procesu
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, Narudžba.[Status predmeta] " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik INNER JOIN Narudžba ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudžba.ID_VU " _
            & "WHERE Narudžba.[Status predmeta] = 'U procesu' " _



ElseIf Frame2 = 3 Then 'Na čekanju
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, Narudžba.[Status predmeta] " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik INNER JOIN Narudžba ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudžba.ID_VU " _
            & "WHERE Narudžba.[Status predmeta] = 'Na čekanju' " _



ElseIf Frame2 = 4 Then 'Fakturirati
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, Narudžba.[Status predmeta] " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik INNER JOIN Narudžba ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudžba.ID_VU " _
            & "WHERE Narudžba.[Status predmeta] = 'Fakturirati' " _



ElseIf Frame2 = 5 Then 'Završeno
strRowsource1 = "SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail, Narudžba.[Status predmeta] " _
            & "FROM Vlasnik INNER JOIN Narudžba ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudžba.ID_VU " _
            & "WHERE Narudžba.[Status predmeta] = 'Završeno' " _






End If


List2.RowSource = strRowsource1


End Sub
```